# What do I need in my package.json file in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I think I'm confused as to what to have in my package.json file for my Meteor app. My app was originally built with v1.2 and recently updated Meteor to 1.4.1.1 (bypassing 1.3). I have no npm packages installed; all my packages were installed through atmosphere. Do I need to list the dependencies of atmosphere packages? I deploy to Modulus. Here's my file:

```
{
  "name": "sonatina_database",
  "private": true,
  "mod-project-name": "SONATINAAPP",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Client database for queries, reports, bulk emails, teaching schedule, etc",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/matt-moon/SonatinaDB.git"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "mj_moon",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/matt-moon/SonatinaDB/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/matt-moon/SonatinaDB#readme",
  "engines": {
    "node": "4.4.7"
  }
}
```

Sorry for the simple question, but it's confusing me.

Answer (score 1):

These aren't a list of dependencies but a list of Meta information for your applications.

It's better to keep this just incase in the future you do decide 'npm' packages later in the future with 'meteor npm install {package name}.

I hope this helps.